# comm without temporary files

Tags: unix, sh, comm

I've been trying to write a single command that takes in a list of single words, sorts, dedupes, compares entries to a dictionary file using comm and finally outputs what isn't in the dictionary.

My current iteration is:

```
sort | uniq > tmp; comm -23 tmp dictionary.txt
```

I am taking input from keyboard above but ideally I wanna save it as a .sh so I can do

```
sh code.sh < wordlist.txt
```

Is there any way I can accomplish the same result without creating that tmp file?

Comment: `comm -23 <(sort "$1" | uniq) dictionary.txt`  you can remove the `<` and just `bash code.sh wordlist.txt`

Comment: Note `bash` not `sh` in Jetchisel's above example. `<(...)` is not guaranteed to work in `sh`. (Similarly, questions about `sh` should be tagged `sh`, not `bash`).

Answer (score 2):

Use a single dash as the filename argument to read from stdin (i.e `sort`'s output).

```
sort -u | comm -23 - dictionary.txt
```

Comment: It workkks! Thank you so much. I didn't know the single dash was an option to read form the other end of the pipe. So much to learn.

Answer (score -1):

You can use a [process substitution](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/ProcessSubstitution):

```
comm -23 <(sort -u wordlist.txt) dictionary.txt
```

A super handy use case for this is to compare contents of files at two other hosts without copying anything:

```
comm -23 <(ssh host1 cat /foo) <(ssh host2 cat /foo)
```

Comment: Thank you! It's great to know an instance where this could be used in the real world :)